# emailBean from Tony McGuckin is not getting attachments after document is saved and reopened

Tags: xpages

I'm using [emailBean from Tony McGuckin](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter) for sending an HTML email.

It works fine until you save and reopen the document; at that point the bean doesn't finds attachments.

Consider this scenario:

1. Create a document and Save it as Draft
2. Open again the document and click on Submit action where it is invoking to logic for emailBean

Runing the bean on debugmode I see it prints Adding Attachments...

But, it is not getting the attachment here `EmbeddedObject eo = this.getDocument().getDocument().getAttachment(persistentName);`

If I try to print `persistentName` I get null

This is emailBean:

```
            // add attachments....
            final List<FileRowData> attachments = this.getDocument().getAttachmentList(this.getFieldName());
            if(null != attachments && !attachments.isEmpty()){
              if(this.isDebugMode()){
                System.out.println("Adding Attachments...");
              }
                for(FileRowData attachment : attachments) {
                emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                if(null != emailRootChild && attachment instanceof AttachmentValueHolder){
                  InputStream is = null;
                  try {                   

                    String persistentName = ((AttachmentValueHolder)attachment).getPersistentName();
                    String cid = ((AttachmentValueHolder)attachment).getCID();

                    //Here is printing null for persistentName
                    System.out.println("Attachment: " + persistentName);

                    EmbeddedObject eo = this.getDocument().getDocument().getAttachment(persistentName);
                    if(null != eo){
                      emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
                      emailHeader.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + persistentName + "\"");
                      emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-ID");
                      emailHeader.setHeaderVal("<" + cid + ">");
                      is = eo.getInputStream();
                      Stream stream = session.createStream();
                      stream.setContents(is);
                      emailRootChild.setContentFromBytes(stream, attachment.getType(), MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
                      if(this.isDebugMode()){
                        System.out.println("Added Attachment : " + persistentName);
                      }
                    }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    if(this.isDebugMode()){
                      System.out.println("Adding Attachment failed : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    throw e;
                  } finally {
                    if(null != is){
                      is.close();
                      is = null;
                    }
                  }
                }
                }
              if(this.isDebugMode()){
                System.out.println("Completed Adding Attachments");
              }
            }
```

Comment: How do you add the attachments to your "draft email"? Are you using the File-Upload-Control?

Comment: Yes,  I'm using a rich text  control and file-upload-control both binded to same RTF field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments in the AttachmentValueHolder field is either persistent or not. A new attachment that has not been saved yet will have a `persistentName`. Otherwise it will have a `name`. You may add the following line to determine that:

```
if(StringUtil.isEmpty(persistentName)) {
    persistentName=((AttachmentValueHolder)attachment).getName();
}
```

*PS. So if persistentName is null, it won't be a persistent name anymore. I didn't change variable name not to ruin your code :)*